# Inserting information into database using the new pdo method giving me an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to migrate from the old SQL method to the new PDO methods for dealing with database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
try{
$conn = new PDO(.......)//this code is working fine
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(name,username,password)VALUES(:name,:username,:password)";

$prepare_query = $conn->prepare($query);

$prepare_query->bindValue(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepare_query->bindValue(':username',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepare_query->bindValue(':password',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$count = $conn->exec($prepare_query);//error is somewhere here
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

if($count > 0) echo "done";
```

Now the error I am receiving is Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\drug_center\includes\NewAccount.php on line 42.

I am a NEWBEE when it comes to the PDO methods. I have read [this](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-exec-insert-update-delete)! but here it is not showing me how to prepare the statement. I  want to protect my data base as much as possible. Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you attach result of var_dump($name); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection object's [`->exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) method expects a string as its first argument containing the query to run, but the prepared statement does what you expect with [`->execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
$success = $prepare_query->execute();
// $success is true if execution was okay
$count = $prepare_query->rowCount();
// $count is the rows affected
```

Comment: The connection object does have an `->exec()` method, it just expects a full string of SQL, not any of these prepared stmt objects.

Comment: @Jack I made the changes and here is the results Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\drug_center\includes\NewAccount.php on line 43
done. Now the script is still printing done to the screen however no information was added to the database.

Comment: @Bryan Sorry, no arguments should be given to `->execute()` of course because they're already bound :)

Answer (score 0):

Try binding in the exec method.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(name,username,password)VALUES(:name,:username,:password)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':name'=>$name,
                  ':username'=>$username,
                      ':password'=>$password));
```